# Destroy GUI window in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I am new to python development and started learning multi-client, server development from  [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-multi-threading-python/) link. I want to tweak this application by adding a close button other than close button provided by window.

```
# GUI class for the chat 
class GUI:
    # constructor method
  def __init__(self):

    # chat window which is currently hidden
    self.Window = Tk()
    self.Window.withdraw()

    # login window
    self.login = Toplevel()
    # set the title
    self.login.title("Login")
    self.login.resizable(width=False,
                         height=False)
    self.login.configure(width=400,
                         height=300)
    # create a Label
    self.pls = Label(self.login,
                     text="Please login to continue",
                     justify=CENTER,
                     font="Helvetica 14 bold")

    self.pls.place(relheight=0.15,
                   relx=0.2,
                   rely=0.07)
    # create a Label
    self.labelName = Label(self.login,
                           text="Name: ",
                           font="Helvetica 12")

    self.labelName.place(relheight=0.2,
                         relx=0.1,
                         rely=0.2)

    # create a entry box for
    # tyoing the message
    self.entryName = Entry(self.login,
                           font="Helvetica 14")

    self.entryName.place(relwidth=0.4,
                         relheight=0.12,
                         relx=0.35,
                         rely=0.2)

    # set the focus of the curser
    self.entryName.focus()

    self.name = self.entryName.get()
    # create a Continue Button
    # along with action
    self.go = Button(self.login,
                     text="CONTINUE",
                     font="Helvetica 14 bold",
                     command=lambda: self.goAhead(self.entryName.get()))

    self.go.place(relx=0.4,
                  rely=0.55)

    self.Window.mainloop()

def goAhead(self, name):
    self.login.destroy()
    self.layout("Client chat")


 # The main layout of the chat
def layout(self, name):

    self.name = name
    # to show chat window
    self.Window.deiconify()
    self.Window.title(self.name)
    self.Window.resizable(width=False,
                          height=False)
    self.Window.configure(width=470,
                          height=550,
                          bg="#17202A")
    self.labelHead = Label(self.Window,
                           bg="#17202A",
                           fg="#EAECEE",
                           text=self.name,
                           font="Helvetica 13 bold",
                           pady=5)

    self.labelHead.place(relwidth=1)
    self.line = Label(self.Window,
                      width=450,
                      bg="#ABB2B9")

    self.line.place(relwidth=1,
                    rely=0.07,
                    relheight=0.012)

    self.textCons = Text(self.Window,
                         width=20,
                         height=2,
                         bg="#17202A",
                         fg="#EAECEE",
                         font="Helvetica 14",
                         padx=5,
                         pady=5)

    self.textCons.place(relheight=0.745,
                        relwidth=1,
                        rely=0.08)

    self.labelBottom = Label(self.Window,
                             bg="#ABB2B9",
                             height=80)

    self.labelBottom.place(relwidth=1,
                           rely=0.825)
    # create a Send Button
    self.buttonMsg = Button(self.labelBottom,
                            text="Close",
                            font="Helvetica 10 bold",
                            width=20,
                            bg="#ABB2B9",
                            command=lambda: self.closeConnection())

    self.buttonMsg.place(relx=0.50,
                         rely=0.008,
                         relheight=0.06,
                         relwidth=0.22)

    self.selectbuttonMsg = Button(self.labelBottom,
                                  text="Select",
                                  font="Helvetica 10 bold",
                                  width=20,
                                  bg="#ABB2B9",
                                  command=lambda: self.readFile())

    self.selectbuttonMsg.place(relx=0.25,
                               rely=0.008,
                               relheight=0.06,
                               relwidth=0.22)

    self.textCons.config(cursor="arrow")

    # create a scroll bar
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.textCons)

    # place the scroll bar
    # into the gui window
    scrollbar.place(relheight=1,
                    relx=0.974)

    scrollbar.config(command=self.textCons.yview)

    self.textCons.config(state=DISABLED)
```

I added button and added function named closeConnection. I used every thing possible, the UI is getting stuck but window is not getting closed.

```
    def closeConnection(self):
        quit()
        self.Window.quit()
        self.Window.destroy()
```

I try to figure out but failing to understand where I am missing. Is it due to threading or due to window deiconify stuff or I am not understanding the window hierarchy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st problem is your indention is off. Make sure to properly space your different levels. That said your code works for me with proper indention. I normally just `root.destroy()`  or in your cose `self.Window.destroy()` with no other code to be executed after the mainloop it should just close everything out. I could be wrong because I normally make the object inherit from `Tk()` and use `self.destroy()` but as I understand things your code should exit out just fine and close everything as there is no other code left to run once the mainloop exits.

Comment: As it is a client server application do you think we need to run root.destroy on another thread?

Comment: Tkinter is not thread save. Meaning it needs to be ran in the main thread to function properly. If you are trying to run Tkinter in another thread that might be part of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have to use this command in order to close the window: `self.root.destroy()`

Comment: There is not an attribute called `root` in the OPs code. `self.Window.destroy()` is correct and should work fine on its own.